# How do you specify a defined sort in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, list, sorting

I have a sharepoint list with a choice column containing the following choices (InProgress, Done, NotStarted, Abandoned etc...) what I'd like to do is sort the list by this column but define the sort order as NotStarted, InProgress, Done, Abandoned rather than an alphabetic sort.

Is there anyway to do this? I have converted my list to an XSLT data view and looked at the sort dialog but cant see a way to define the sort like this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Christian

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to rename your choices in the choice column from `NotStarted, InProgress, Done, Abandoned` to `(1) NotStarted, (2) InProgress, (3) Done, (4) Abandoned`. This is how the Priority column is setup in out of the box Tasks lists.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for the reply, this is exactly what I have done up until now but I think this makes the lists look really messy and is difficult to maintain because if I need to insert a value inbetween 1 & 2 then I need to rename all the choices and then all of the items in the list as well that use it. I was hopeing that there might be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a calculated column that will assign numerical values based on your text ones. Go to `Add Column > More...` and select `Calculation`. In the formula box below, try something like

```
=IF(EXACT(Priority,"High"),1,IF(EXACT(Priority,"Normal"),2,3))
```

Here's a solid reference for [Examples of common formulas in lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us).